# textContent does not change the value in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

so i've got this script:

```
window.onload = function() {
       var myValues = localStorage.getItem("myValues") ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("myValues")) : [];
       var myTables = localStorage.getItem("tableValues") ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("tableValues")) : [];
       makeDuplicates(myTables);
       var divElements = document.querySelectorAll("#namefield");
       for(var i = 0; i < myValues.length; i++) {
           alert("In table: " + divElements[i].textContent + ", trying to change: "+myValues[i]);
           divElements[i].textContent = myValues[i];
       }
   }
```

I did a little test with alert, the element it gets is right and myValue[i] exists but the value in div does not change with the code below alert. I don't know what else should i show in this occasion or is this enough?

As for more clarification - the similar code works in another javascript i'm using for another .html and this particular page loads the table in which i have td which content will be changed before the for cycle starts (got it with alert).

Any ideas why the change does not occur?

Added images for clarification:

[image: IMAGE1]
[image: AFTERCLICK]

This is a link to a HTML: http://pastebin.com/x5sbbj6b

Comment: Please show your HTML. Interested to know just what the element list looks like across browsers, since multiple elements with the same `id` is invalid HTML. Also be aware that `textContent` isn't available in (e.g.) older versions of IE.

Comment: do you really have ALL of your div with id=namefield ???

Comment: I'm using fairly new Opera, and the issue does not occur in the other table.
If you're looking for a testing site, i have it all uploaded to http://kevin.planet.ee aswell. To get this group table check groups and set atleast one table. I'll add 4groups.html as an edit.

Comment: Note: 'textContent' doesn't exist before IE9.